# How can I see the event that is attached to an html element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am a new programmer and still learning.
This is the code that I am trying to figure out:

```
<div id="buy" class="buy button">Buy</div>
```

When I click on the div (button), some JavaScript code is executed but I don't know were it is. How can I tell what function is fired when click happens? Some how a listener is attached to this element.

Comment: Are you asking *how* an event handler is attached to the div?

Comment: side note: you should not use divs as a buttons use <button type="button">Im a button</button> or <a href="www.google.com">Im a link</a> instead.

Comment: @RandyMarsh I don't know were the event listener is, This is what I am trying to find out. Because usually i learned in school that you add can add an onclick attribute in the element and then specify the function that you need to fire. But with firebug when i mouse over on that element I can't see the event :( how do they do this?

Comment: The listener isn't necessarily attached directly to that element. It could be on an ancestor.

Comment: We have FireFox and Chrome solutions.  I wonder about IE... Not holding my breath.

Comment: Chrome's Event Listener Rocks!!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you use Firefox and Firebug you can try installing FireQuery. It will make it so you can *see* the handlers bound by jQuery. http://firequery.binaryage.com/

Comment: How do you know it was attached using jQuery?

Comment: FireQuery seems to be what I was looking for, With this tool I can always know what events are binded to any elements? and also the onchange events, onmouseover etc.. ?

Comment: this will not work for events bound by DOM Level 1+2 listeners with plain Javascript

Comment: @kissmyface: He said *"If you use Firefox"*, which isn't relevant to my comment.

Comment: jQuery event handlers are also located in jQuery's data cache making them accessible using $().data('events') on any valid selector.

Answer (score 106):

In Google chrome's developer tools (click the wrench icon >Tools>Developer tools), select the element in the Elements tab, on the right open the 'Event Listeners'  panel you'll will see all events

Comment: For those who love hotkeys, pressing F12 opens this as well.

Comment: @yoelp <div class="comm"> <a href="#">A</a> </div>. When I check 'Event Listeners' for the anchor, it shows Click-> a (jquery.min.js). The corresponding click event handler function is in 'navigation.js', why its showing jquery.min.js instead of navigation.js. Do you want me to raise a separate question for this?

Comment: @SyAu because the event is being bound by jQuery not by navigation.js, navigation.js is just calling the jQuery bind function, But the actually binding happens in Jquery

Answer (score 13):

You can't do it in a really good manner by "just" using ECMAscript itself. For instance, if there was a click event handler added by *DOM Level 1* in the form of

```
document.getElementById('buy').onclick = function() {};
```

you can of course easily intercept that property on the node itself. Things are getting more complicated if *DOM Level 2* comes into play with `.addEventListener()` respectevily `.attachEvent()`. Now you don't really have a "place" to look for where all the different listener functions where bound from.

It gets better by using jQuery. jQuery will hold all it's event handler functions in a special object which is linked to the DOM node of invocation. You can check for that by getting the `.data()`-expando property for a node like

```
$('#buy').data('events');
```

However, now I already described three different ways of binding event listeners to a node (actually its two because a library like jQuery also uses DOM Level 1 or 2 methods of course).

It's really getting ugly if an event is triggerd by delegation. That means, we bound our click event on some parent-node just waiting for that event bubbling up to us so we can check the `target`. So now we don't even have a direct relationship between the `node` and the `event listener`.

Conclusion here is, lookout of a browser plugin or probably a thing like [VisualEvent](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event).

Comment: +1 Thorough answer. Only thing is that the `.data('events')` solution won't help if the event is bound to an ancestor.

Answer (score 9):

You may use "[Visual Event 2](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2)" script as a bookmark or same script as [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pbmmieigblcbldgdokdjpioljjninaim).

This script shows all js events attached to dom-elements.

Comment: All DOM level 0 events and all events from known versions of widely used frameworks (jQuery, Prototype, Mootools, YUI etc.), actually. It cannot show DOM level 2 event observer attached via pure JavaScript.

Answer (score 5):

Use `jQuery("#buy").data('events');`

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/ may be interesting.

Comment: How do you know it was bound with jQuery, and bound directly to the element?

Comment: Console says it is "undefined".

Answer (score 4):

Event handlers attached using traditional `element.onclick=` handler or HTML `<element onclick="handler">` can be retrieved trivially from the `element.onclick` property from script or in-debugger.

Event handlers attached using DOM Level 2 Events addEventListener methods and IE's attachEvent cannot currently be retrieved from script at all. DOM Level 3 once proposed element.eventListenerList to get all listeners, but it is unclear whether this will make it to the final specification. There is no implementation in any browser today.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using FireFox, you should have FireBug installed. Once you have that, you can install FireQuery, which will show you what jQuery events are bound to which objects.

http://getfirebug.com/

http://firequery.binaryage.com/

Comment: How do you know it was attached using jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using jQuery?  If so, you want to search for one of these three lines of code:

```
$("#buy").click //the div is refered by its id
```

or

```
$(".buy").click //the div is refered to by the style "buy"
```

or

```
$(".button").click //refered to by the style "button"
```

Most newer browsers have "Developer Tools" built into them by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> (at least in IE and Chrome).  That may help you do some further debugging and tracing.

Comment: thanx, I can see the body of the function when I alert but I can't see where it is located so I can edit it.

Comment: There are many more ways to bind an element than just those. Even if `click` was used, the selector may be very different.

Answer (score 2):

Below is something I’ve used in the past that I think may be what you're looking for.  What this does is watch a property on a page element (In the example below, it's the document's "Title" property) and then display an alert with the JS callstack whenever that property is changed.  You’ll need to get this into the DOM before whatever code you're trying to find fires, but hopefully you’ll be able to identify what’s causing the problem.

I would recommend using Firefox and getting Firebug for JavaScript debugging.

```
// Call stack code
function showCallStack() {
   var f=showCallStack,result="Call stack:\n";

   while((f=f.caller)!==null) {
      var sFunctionName = f.toString().match(/^function (\w+)\(/)
      sFunctionName = (sFunctionName) ? sFunctionName[1] : 'anonymous function';
      result += sFunctionName;
      result += getArguments(f.toString(), f.arguments);
      result += "\n";
   }
   alert(result);
}


function getArguments(sFunction, a) {
   var i = sFunction.indexOf(' ');
   var ii = sFunction.indexOf('(');
   var iii = sFunction.indexOf(')');
   var aArgs = sFunction.substr(ii+1, iii-ii-1).split(',')
   var sArgs = ''; 
   for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
      var q = ('string' == typeof a[i]) ? '"' : '';
      sArgs+=((i>0) ? ', ' : '')+(typeof a[i])+' '+aArgs[i]+':'+q+a[i]+q+'';
   }
   return '('+sArgs+')';
} 

var watchTitle = function(id, oldval, newval) { showCallStack(); }

// !! This is all you should need to update, setting it to whatever you want to watch.
document.watch("title", watchTitle);
```

Comment: The `watch` method is presumably only supported by Firefox (Gecko browsers)?

Answer (score 2):

This is the easiest way I've found of how to do it: 
http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event

> When working with events in Javascript, it is often easy to lose track
>   of what events are subscribed where. This is particularly true if you
>   are using a large number of events, which is typical in a modern
>   interface employing progressive enhancement. Javascript libraries also
>   add another degree of complexity to listeners from a technical point
>   of view, while from a developers point of view they of course can make
>   life much easier! But when things go wrong it can be difficult to
>   trace down why this might be.
>
> It is due to this I've put together a Javascript bookmarklet called
>   Visual Event which visually shows the elements on a page that have
>   events subscribed to them, what those events are and the function that
>   the event would run when triggered. This is primarily intended to
>   assist debugging, but it can also be very interesting and informative
>   to see the subscribed events on other pages.

There's a bookmark button there you can drag to your toolbar (FF or Chrome), then just click the button on any page where you want to see the events attached.  Works great! (at least for events attached by jQuery or other libraries).

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click page, and choose to view the page's source
2. Find `<script>` tags
3. Look for `$("#buy")` and something mentioning `onClick` or `.on("click",function(){...});`
4. If you can't find it, search for something along these lines: `document.getElementById("buy")`
5. You have found the `function`, or code, where the event handler code is

`$("#buy")` is JQuery's way of saying find an element that has an `id` attribute of `buy` and if it has a `.` following it with some function, that function is acting upon the element that was found by JQuery.

Comment: What if it was bound to an ancestor?

Comment: it has to be at an external source :S

Comment: @VasoApostolidou If so there will be `<script src="..." type="text/javascript"></script>` somewhere on the page. Find that JS file in the `src` attribute and navigate to it.